# Python Netsnmp and snmpwalk

Tags: python, linux, snmp, net-snmp

I am trying to use snmpwalk to gain some info and stats on some interfaces. I use this:

```
import netsnmp

serv = "172.16.1.1"
snmp_pass = "private"

oid = netsnmp.VarList('IF-MIB::ifName','IF-MIB::ifDescr')
snmp_res = netsnmp.snmpwalk(oid, Version=2, DestHost=serv, Community=snmp_pass)
for x in snmp_res:
    print "snmp_res:: ", x
```

All I get as answer is:

```
snmp_res:: lo
snmp_res:: EtherNet Adapter XYZ
```

The answer is correct but I want more info. When I do same thing from linux command with snmpwalk I get more info such as:

```
IF-MIB::ifDescr.1 = STRING: lo
IF-MIB::ifDescr.2 = STRING: EtherNet Adapter XYZ
```

The ID is 2 for "EtherNet Adapter XYZ" and I need that value as well to reference for other stats on interface. How do I get that/them with python and snmp?

Comment: Have you examined the returned objects to see if more information isn't being returned?  All you're seeing is a string representation

Comment: I have tried with little luck. I imagine I look at "oid"?  It appears to be a "<class 'netsnmp.client.VarList'>".  I am really needing ID matched to interface name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight out of [the documentation](https://github.com/hardaker/net-snmp/blob/master/python/README):

> `snmpwalk(<Varbind/VarList>, <Session args>))`
>
> Takes args of netsnmp.Session preceded by a Varbind or
>                  VarList from which the 'walk' operation will start.
>                  Returns a tuple of values retrieved from the MIB below
>                  the Varbind passed in.  **If a VarList is passed in it
>                  will be updated to contain a complete set of VarBinds
>                  created for the results of the walk.**  It is not
>                  recommended to pass in just a Varbind since you loose
>                  the ability to examine the returned OIDs.  But, if only
>                  a Varbind is passed in it will be returned unaltered.
>
> Note that only one varbind should be contained in the
>                  VarList passed in.  The code is structured to maybe
>                  handle this is the the future, but right now walking
>                  multiple trees at once is not yet supported and will
>                  produce insufficient results.

You're already passing a *VarList*, so you already have what you need. You just need to examine the results properly.

[The tests](https://github.com/hardaker/net-snmp/blob/master/python/netsnmp/tests/test.py) have an example:

```
vars = netsnmp.VarList(netsnmp.Varbind('system'))

vals = sess.walk(vars)
print "v1 sess.walk result: ", vals, "\n"

for var in vars:
    print "  ",var.tag, var.iid, "=", var.val, '(',var.type,')'
```

The key is that the *input* variable is modified to give you what you need. The return value is not of much value (lol) to you.

Putting this all together it looks like you want the following:

```
import netsnmp

serv = "172.16.1.1"
snmp_pass = "private"

oid = netsnmp.VarList('IF-MIB::ifName','IF-MIB::ifDescr')
snmp_res = netsnmp.snmpwalk(oid, Version=2, DestHost=serv, Community=snmp_pass)
for x in oid:
    print "snmp_res:: ", x.iid, " = ", x.val
```

*(Disclaimer: can't test; adapt as needed)*

There's enough information about *VarBind* and *VarList* in that documentation to figure out the best stuff to get out of `x`.

`x.iid` is the instance identifier, though, so that should give you the `1` and `2` that you're after. Don't forget to examine `x.tag` as well, though, which will be either `IF-MIB::ifName` or `IF-MIB::ifDescr` (or something equivalent; you'd have to experiment).

Comment: Is there a way to do a bulkwalk rather than a walk with python and snmp? The walk operation is terribly slow.

Comment: @Matt I only know what's in the docs, and it's not listed in the docs. Then again, it's pretty easy to implement with `getbulk` in a loop and a bit of conditional logic to break when you leave your desired subtree.